# One logj4 log not showing while the same under it shows. How can this happen?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, resttemplate

I have something like this:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, responseType);
logger.debug("Scheduled request success: " + scheduledRequest.getMethod() + " " + scheduledRequest.getUrl() + " "
                    + responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());

logger.debug("something else");
```

`"something else"` always shows. The above debug message also shows most of the times except for when there is a problem with the request. The log is there exactly because I want to find out what that problem is but it just doesn't show anything. And it clearly doesn't throw an Exception because the bellow log always displays its information. What should I do?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried to add a log before the call to `restTemplate.exchange(...)` ?

Comment: No, but every other log message in the application works. And I'm mainly interested in the responseEntity status code. The other details are just so that I'd know for what request this happened.

Comment: What about debugging that code? Are you not able to debug it and check it step by step? Maybe you have a `logger.debug("something else");` line somewhere else and it is misleading you

Comment: Unfortunately I can't debug it because I don't know how it happens. It probably causes a problem for 1/100 users. The whole thing is in a massive try catch but it never goes into a catch.

Comment: Also the other log doesn't really just say "something else" but I felt the code was pointless. There is a debug message there and it works.

Comment: I think realistically the only way you can track this down is by adding a whole load more debug statements. Maybe start by splitting that one long debug message into 3 separate ones, one for each value you're logging. Could it possibly be to do with the length of messages? Or something to do with the content in the `getUrl()` result that's causing your logging config to suppress this message?

Comment: Yeah this is probably what I'm going to do unless someone else has encountered this and knows a solution.